# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\sin{(x^3-1)}\cos(\frac{1}{1-x})}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\sin{(x^3-1)}\cos(\frac{1}{1-x})}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

My attempt: $\cos(\frac{1}{1-x})=\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})$, so if we let $t=x-1$ we get
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\sin{(x^3-1)}\cos(\frac{1}{x-1})}{\sqrt{x-1}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin{((t+1)^3-1)}\cos(\frac{1}{t})}{\sqrt{t}}$$ That's where I got stuck because this doesn't look any better I guess. Any hint?

Comment: $\frac{\sin ((t+1)^3-1)}{(t+1)^3-1}\to 1$ and $|\cos\frac 1t|\le 1$, the result will be $0$.

Comment: What about the term $\frac{(t+1)^3-1}{\sqrt{t}}$? Do we just "ignore" it because $0$ times that other term is equal to $0$?

Comment: $\frac{t^3+3t^2+3t+1-1}{t}\cdot\sqrt{t}\to 0$, we don't 'ignore' it. And then yes, squeeze theorem as mentioned in the answers (to get rid of $\cos \frac 1t$).

Comment: Oh, just noticed that $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\rightarrow1^+$ we obtain: $$\frac{\sin{(x^3-1)}\cos(\frac{1}{1-x})}{\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{\sin(x^3-1)}{x^3-1}\cdot\sqrt{x-1}(x^2+x+1)\cos\frac{1}{x-1}\rightarrow0.$$